# How to update current user in access database via c#

Tags: c#, parameters, sql-update, oledb, ms-access-2013

I'm having problems updating(editing) current user data (user that is currently logged in application).

I'm using C# WPF and im trying to update(edit) it via UPDATE statement.

I'm having problems with program recognizing user ID (at least i think so).

How can i update current user, without user entering his ID, because ID is a data only administrator is supposed to know in this case.

If i leave out the WHERE[ID] = ? , it updates the same data for all the users.

This is my code

```
try
        {
            //CONNECTION STRING ALREADY CONNECTED
            cmd.Connection = db;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET [Name] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [UserName] = ?, [Password] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Email] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", eMail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "?");             

            db.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("User updated!");
            db.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: When you have selected the data for update did you retrieve also the ID of the  user that you want to update?

Comment: The same user you logged in you want to update?

Comment: @Steve Im not sure i understand what you mean. Im updating data via textboxes.

Comment: I mean, when you initialize the content of the textboxes, did you read the values from the database? `(SELECT .... FROM [USER] WHERE ID=....)`, in that point you have the ID needed also for the UPDATE statement

Comment: @Avi yeah, it's an "application" where user's can buy train tickets. It's logical that there should be option to update(edit) their data in case they change mail or home address

Comment: @Steve oh i get it now. No Not yet, im not sure how to display data in textBoxes yet (im sorry im pretty new at that).

Comment: can you able to edit that database ? i mean can you add some extra column in that?

Answer (score 0):

You have square brackets around every field but not on the table name.
USER is a reserved keyword in MS-Access. So put square brakets around it also otherwise you will get a syntax error when executing the update.

Of course the ID parameter value should be set if you want to update only the record of that specific user.

I am pretty sure that, when you load the data from the database and put it in the textboxes for the operator to edit, you have also the ID for this specific user.

At that point, in your code, you could save the ID value somewhere in your window class (a global variable, an hidden field) and then retrieve it when you need to save.

Comment: Im not yet displaying data in textBoxes because im not sure how to do that yet, but i guess that if i would've done that, the data + ID would get displayed and i'd have no problems with the updates, because it would display the ID ?

Comment: I suppose that you are starting from the end. The first thing you should do is to retrieve the data that you want to update. Then and only then approach the problem to update that data.

Comment: can you give me any tips or links on how to retrieve data from database and into textboxes for wpf in c#. I've been searching but i can't rly find anything useful. I know i need to use SELECT * FROM, but thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

you said you have permission to create the column in database it is regarding to this.

create the column with `Auto-Generated` with datatype `GUID`.
while selecting user information select this column also. 
save this id somewhere in code.
and use it to update the record.

i am telling you to create `GUID` column because its never same at same time in same network